# Replacing value in text file using ant script

Tags: ant

I have the following in a  text file

BuildVersion:R2
TestVersion:1000
AndroidVersion:6.0

and I need to Change "TestVersion" value dynamically using ant script??
Please advise,

Answer (score 5):

Use a placeholder for "TestVersion" and replace it during the build process.
Your text file will look like this:

```
BuildVersion:R2 @@TestVersion@@:1000 AndroidVersion:6.0
```

and your ant file will contain the following `target` element to replace @@TestVersion@@ with some other value:

```
<target name="replaceTestVersion">
    <replace file="YOUR_FILE">
        <replacefilter token="@@TestVersion@@" value="YOUR_NEW_VALUE" />
    </replace>
</target>
```